# How to refer to id kivy and kivy md?

Tags: python, kivy

What's wrong with python code and kivy, when I don't put @ and . on text input, it does the opposite that what I am waiting for. Here is the code. My real question is how to refer to a text input on another?

```
    def check_text(self):
        screen = self.root.get_screen('register')
        e_mail = screen.ids.e_mail.text
        age = screen.ids.age.text
        full_name = screen.ids.full_name.text
        password = screen.ids.password.text
        address = screen.ids.address.text
        if (not '@' and '.' in e_mail) and len(e_mail) < 6:
            toast("Please enter a valid e-mail.")
        else:
            return e_mail
        if len(full_name) < 5:
            toast("Please enter yout full name.")
        else:
            return full_name
        if not "@" or "#" or '&' or '-' or '_' or "+" and not "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" in password and len(password) < 8:
            toast("Please read the conditions for a secure password.")
        else:
            return password
        if len(password) < 8:
            toast("Please enter a valid password.")
        else:
            return password
        if len(address) < 10:
            toast("Please enter a valid address.")
        else:
            return address
        if int(age) < 15:
            toast("You need to be aged of at least 15 years old to use Reviewin.")
        else:
            return int(age)
        if len(address) < 10 and int(age) < 15 and len(password) < 8 and len(full_name) < 5 and not  "@" or "#" or '&' or '-' or '_' or "+" and not "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" in password:
            toast("Please register correctly ! ")
        else:
            return something
```

````
MDScreen:
    name:"register"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Happy to see you here !"
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.55, 'center_y':0.95}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            font_size: "24sp"
            font_name: "Inter"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Before beggining, just create an account..."
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.90}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color:'Custom'
            font_size: "16sp"
            font_name: "Inter"
        MDLabel:
            text: "We are waiting for you..."
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.85}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            font_size: "18sp"
            font_name: "Inter"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Register"
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            font_size: "24sp"
            font_name:"OpenSans"
        MDLabel:
            text:"or"
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.44, 'center_y':0.77}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            font_size: "18sp"
        Button:
            text: "[u]login[/u]"
            markup: True
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.55, 'center_y': 0.77}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            color: 11/255, 206/255, 232/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.15, 0.015)
            background_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
            background_normal: ''
            on_press: app.root.current = "login"
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id:full_name
            text: ""
            hint_text: "Full Name"
            size_hint_x:  None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            icon_right: "email"
            id: e_mail
            hint_text: "E-Mail"
            size_hint_x:  None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.6}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: address
            hint_text: "Address"
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: age
            hint_text: "Age"
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            input_filter: 'int'
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            icon_left: 'key-variant'
            icon_right: 'eye-off'
            id: password
            hint_text: "Password"
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: gender
            hint_text: "MALE OR FEMALE"
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Finish !"
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.1}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color:'Custom'
            text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.58, 0.06)
            md_bg_color: 62/255, 216/255, 133/255, 1
            background_normal:''
            on_press: app.check_text()
    ```
````

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Hi @ApuCoder , here is the code i don't understand the output : 
```
    def check_text(self):
        screen = self.root.get_screen('register')
        e_mail = screen.ids.e_mail.text
        age = screen.ids.age.text
        full_name = screen.ids.full_name.text
        password = screen.ids.password.text
        address = screen.ids.address.text
        if (not '@' and '.' in e_mail) and len(e_mail) < 6:
            toast("Please enter a valid e-mail.")
        else:
            print("it's okay")
```